# Why $x/N(x)$ and $y/N(y)$ are members of $B$? Is $\frac{N(x)}{N(x)+N(y)}=\lambda\in [0,1]$ and $\frac{N(y)}{N(x)+N(y)} = 1-\lambda$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a lemma that I don't understand some part of in my textbook. Here are some defintions that it uses:

Definition of a norm:

> A norm on a vector space $X$ is a map $\|\cdot\|:X\to[0,\infty)$ such that:
> (i)$\|x\|=0 $ if and only if $x=0$;
> (ii) $\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$;
> (iii) $\|x+y\|\leq \|x\|+\|y\|$ for every $x,y\in X$.

> Lemma: Suppose $N:X\to [0,\infty)$ satisfies (i) and (ii) of the defintion of a norm and in addition that the set $B:=\{x:N(x)\leq 1\}$ is convex. Then $N$ satisfies the triangle inequality
> \begin{gather*}
> N(x+y)\leq N(x)+N(y) \tag{1}
> \end{gather*}
> and so defines a norm on $X$.
> Proof:
> We only need to prove (1). If $N(x)=0$ then $x=0$ and $$N(x+y)=N(y)=N(x)+N(y),$$
> so we can assume that $N(x)>0$ and $N(y)>0$.
> In this case $x/N(x)\in B$ and $y/N(y)\in B$, so using the convexity of $B$ we have $$\frac{N(x)}{N(x)+N(y)}\biggl(\frac{x}{N(x)}\biggr)+\frac{N(y)}{N(x)+N(y)}\biggl(\frac{y}{N(y)}\biggr) \in B.$$
> So
> $$\frac{x+y}{N(x)+N(y)}\in B,$$
> which means, using property (ii) from definition of a norm that $$N\biggl(\frac{x+y}{N(x)+N(y)}\biggr)=\frac{N(x+y)}{N(x)+N(y)}\leq 1 \Rightarrow N(x+y)\leq N(x)+N(y).$$

What I don't particularly understand is why $x/N(x)$ and $y/N(y)$ are members of $B$?

Also, in the context of this expression:

$$\frac{N(X)}{N(x)+N(y)}\biggl(\frac{x}{N(x)}\biggr)+\frac{N(y)}{N(x)+N(y)}\biggl(\frac{y}{N(y)}\biggr) \in B$$

Is it implied that $\frac{N(x)}{N(x)+N(y)}=\lambda\in [0,1]$ and $\frac{N(y)}{N(x)+N(y)} = 1-\lambda$ (Since by definition of convexity, that's what implied)? And if yes, then how do we know they are equal to $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N(\frac x {N(x)})=N(cx)$ wheer $c=\frac  1{N(x)}$. By (ii) we get $N(\frac x {N(x)})=cN(x)=\frac 1 {N(x)} N(x)=1$ which implies $\frac x {N(x)} \in B$.

For your second  question define $\lambda$ as $\frac {N(x)} {N(x)+N(y)}$ and calculate $1-\lambda$. You will get $1-\lambda=\frac {N(y)} {N(x)+N(y)}$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining so well! Do you mind explaining the second question?